# parameter of mapDispatchToProps is not defined

Tags: reactjs, redux

on mapDispatchToProps i try declare a method for dispatch a action called handleSubmit, but react say handleSubmit is not defined, it is defined inside the class, but i try a lot of and i cant resolve it

```
import React from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";
import connect from "react-redux/es/connect/connect";


 class Login extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super();

        this.state = {
            email: '',
            senha: '',
        };

    }

    handleChange = e => this.setState({...this.state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});


    handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="container">

                    <div className="card">

                        <div className="card-logo">

                        </div>

                        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="card-form">
                            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" id={'email'} name={'email'} value={this.state.email}
                                   onChange={this.handleChange}/>

                            <label htmlFor="senha">Senha</label>
                            <input type="text" id={'senha'} value={this.state.senha}
                                   name={'senha'} onChange={this.handleChange}/>

                            <input type="submit" value={'Logar'} />
                        </form>

                    </div>


                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }

}

const mapsStateToProps = state => ({usuario: state})
const mapDispatchToprops = dispatch => bindActionCreators({handleSubmit}, dispatch)

export default connect(mapsStateToProps, mapDispatchToprops)(Login)
```

How i can fix it? i try do

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    handleSubmit: () => {
      dispatch(handleSubmit());
    }
  };
};
```

wihout using bindActionsCreators, but i give some error:'handleSubmit' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Where is your action creator? You need to create actions. `handleSubmitAction` must be created.

Comment: its really, now i see how i use the action creator. Thank you very much